# Why is this nested IF statement not returning my intended values?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying this formula in Excel.
This nested IF statement is not returning the values I've intended.  The cell in the statement can be between 1.000 and 0.000.  If the value in the cell is equal to 1 it always returns a value of "1", if it is less than 1 it is always returning a value of "3", even when the value is 0.  What am I missing with this IF statement?

```
=IF(F5=1,"4",
    IF(1>F5>=0.9,"3",
        IF(0.9>F5>=0.75,"2",
            IF(0.75>F5>=0.55,"1",
                IF(F5<0.5,"0")))))
```

Comment: What does this have to do with windows? Don;t you want to tag this with EXCEL?

Comment: @JHCC check the answer below. Your formula was wrong. I tested at my end and it works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

To do between range in excel it would be done using [`AND(logical1, [logical2], ...)`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/and-function-HP010069828.aspx)

```
IF(AND(XXX>=YYY,XXX<=ZZZ)...
```

so your check would look like

```
IF(AND(F5>=0.9,f5<1)...
```

Comment: So I guessed the problem correctly. I just don't know excel well enough to suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

i am going to guess.. you cannot have things like 1>f5>=0.9 in the if-condition, as it's possibly evaluating left-to-right, (1>f5 == true) ,  (true>=0.9 == true) hence you get 3 all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Excel codes `True` as `1` and `False` as `0`.  So `1>F5>=0.9` is parsed as `(1>F5)>=0.9`.  This becomes `True >= 0.9` which is the same as `1 >= 0.9` which is `True`.

As epascarello pointed out, you can properly create a check for an interval with `AND(F5>=0.9,f5<1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected formula.

```
=IF(F5=1,"4",IF(AND(1>F5,F5>=0.9),"3",IF(AND(0.9>F5,F5>=0.75),"2",IF(AND(0.75>F5,F5>=0.55),"1",IF(F5<0.5,"0","ENTER_A_VALUE_HERE")))))
```

When you are carrying out 2 logical operation in IF statement, use AND(expression1, expression2,....expression N) format.

You should be able to look at the corrected function above and see the difference.

Reference: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/if.php